# Update Gnome Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: 14.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I would like to update my Gnome Shell to the latest version for Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Can I upgrade to the latest version(that appears on Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.04.1?), or will be updated to the latest supported version(without breaking my system) of my Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.5 LTS?

Gnome shell version: `GNOME Shell 3.10.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the latest version of Gnome on 14.04 is 3.10 and trying to upgrade Gnome past 3.12 would crash your system.
If you would like a more recent version of Gnome you should upgrade to 16.04.1 which ships with 3.18 out of the box.

In short: Gnome 14.04 won't go past Gnome 3.10 despite the distro's life cycle is ongoing.

Comment: So the best stable GNOME version for Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.5 LTS is 3.12?

Comment: It's not stable, it's experimental! I've installed it myself and the cons outweigh the pros, I had so many problems and bugs to deal with.

Comment: Oh no. Did you revert back to 3.10? What happened?

Comment: To fix my issues I decided to download a clean version of Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.4 (it was the latest at the time) and preformed a clean install, it worked like a charm! 
Please if my feedback helped you mark my answer as the answer to close the question and mark it solved.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback,  you already had my tick. :D I just wanted to be very sure with upgrading my GNOME version. I will stick to my 3.10 then. :)